# plotting a function i

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab, math-software, maple, mathematica

How can i plot bellow function in MAPLE or MATHEMATICA or MATLAB?

$$y=0.05+0.1\cdot e^{0.01x}\cdot \cos(0.2\cdot x)$$

while $x$ can be in the range of $ -350$ to $+350$ or less.

Thank you

Comment: I´ve made an edit and improved your formatting. Please check if it is right and give a reply.

Comment: By the way, there are **no** complex values of $y$. See the graph [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+0.05%2B0.1%5Ccdot+e%5E%7B0.01x%7D%5Ccdot+%5Ccos%280.2%5Ccdot+x%29%2C+-350%3Cx%3C350) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica

```
Plot[0.05 + 0.1 Exp[0.01 x] Cos[0.2 x],
 {x, -350, 350},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the following for MATLAB:

```
x=linspace(-350,350,100000)
y=0.05+0.1*exp(0.01*x).*cos(0.2*x)
plot(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maple

```
y := 0.05 + 0.1*exp(0.01*x)*cos(0.2*x):
plot(y, x=-350 .. 350);
```

Or,

```
plot(0.05 + 0.1*exp(0.01*x)*cos(0.2*x),
     x=-350 .. 350);
```

And see the help page for topic **plot,options** for additional options and tweaks.

It's difficult to see how you could fail to figure out how to do this most basic of things -- plot a univariate expression over a given domain -- unless you have not looked at even the introductory help pages in any of those three commercial products.